# Python: How to get number of mili seconds per jiffy

Tags: python, linux

I'd like to know the HZ of the system, i.e. how many mili seconds is one jiffy from Python code.

Comment: the timer interrupt interval, which determines the accuracy of all thread sleep operations, etc

Comment: @knitti, "I'll get that for you in one jiffy". I think its equal to "real quick".

Comment: Anything to do with `antique_chinese_email_message.decode('hz')` ?

Comment: Python is a high-level language which makes any number you'll get pretty much meaningless. So... any specific thing you need it for?

Comment: IIRC Python's threading is weird and the OS does the scheduling for it?

Comment: @THC4k the OS does the scheduling for most threading libraries, including those normally used in Java, C++ and C# on Linux.

Comment: @WoLpH being a high-level language doesn't mean you can'd to low-level things with it. Like reading /proc.

Comment: @MarkR: That is true, but you won't be able to do anything meaningful with jiffies in Python. And if it's just reading, than what's the purpose?

Comment: @WoLpH all sorts of things - monitoring, performance measurement, hung task detection

Comment: @MarkR: hung task detection by reading the jiffies per millisecond from `/proc` with Python? I recommend you read up on how jiffies are defined on modern computers. I believe that your definition is either incorrect or simply outdated.

Comment: @wolph I may detect hung tasks by observing how much "progress" they are making. Of course I'd also need to know what those tasks were, but I might do if they were my own processes. The possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 25):

There is USER_HZ

```
>>> import os
>>> os.sysconf_names['SC_CLK_TCK']
2
>>> os.sysconf(2)
100
```

which is what the kernel uses to report time in `/proc`.

From the `time(7)` manual page:

> **The Software Clock, HZ, and Jiffies**
>
> The  accuracy  of  various  system  calls  that  set  timeouts,  (e.g.,
>   select(2), sigtimedwait(2)) and measure CPU time  (e.g.,  getrusage(2))
>   is  limited by the resolution of the software clock, a clock maintained
>   by the kernel which measures time in jiffies.  The size of a  jiffy  is
>   determined by the value of the kernel constant HZ.
>
> The  value  of HZ varies across kernel versions and hardware platforms.
>   On i386 the situation is as follows: on kernels  up  to  and  including
>   2.4.x,  HZ was 100, giving a jiffy value of 0.01 seconds; starting with
>   2.6.0, HZ was raised to 1000, giving a jiffy of 0.001  seconds.   Since
>   kernel 2.6.13, the HZ value is a kernel configuration parameter and can
>   be 100, 250 (the default) or 1000, yielding a jiffies value of, respec‐
>   tively,  0.01, 0.004, or 0.001 seconds.  Since kernel 2.6.20, a further
>   frequency is available: 300, a number that divides evenly for the  com‐
>   mon video frame rates (PAL, 25 HZ; NTSC, 30 HZ).
>
> The  times(2)  system  call is a special case.  It reports times with a
>   granularity defined by the kernel constant USER_HZ.  Userspace applica‐
>   tions    can    determine    the   value   of   this   constant   using
>   sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK).

If you absolutely must know SYSTEM_HZ:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> rt = CDLL('librt.so')
>>> CLOCK_REALTIME = 0
>>> class timespec(Structure):
...     _fields_ = [("tv_sec", c_long), ("tv_nsec", c_long)]
... 
>>> res = timespec()
>>> rt.clock_getres(CLOCK_REALTIME, byref(res))
0
>>> res.tv_sec, res.tv_nsec
(0, 4000250)
>>> SYSTEM_HZ = round(1/(res.tv_sec + (res.tv_nsec/10.0**9)))
```

Gives 250 on my laptop (which sounds about right) and 1000000000 in a VM…

Comment: I'm trying to calculate some stuff based on jiffies which should really be in ms. So, if know HZ equivalent, then jiffies * 1000/os.sysconf(2) = ms. At least I think so.

Comment: where do your jiffies come from? also, your equation is weird.

Comment: jiffies come from stime, utime and other timing related proeprties found in /proc/stat and similar files. Equation comes from unixtop.org. elapsed = timediff.tv_sec * HZ + (timediff.tv_usec * HZ) / 1000000; Since HZ is not available in Python, I was looking for the alternative.

Comment: @Murgh: those are reported in USER_HZ, so what are you still missing?

Comment: @hop: Well yes, they are in jiffies, but to get the elapsed time in jiffies from timeA to timeB i need to multiply the ms with HZ. So I need to know the HZ in order to calculate it.

Comment: @Murgh: i _gave_ you the hz!!??!

Comment: @hop: Yeah thanks for that, I'm still half way through with the rest of the problem, so will try multiplying the ms with the SYSTEM_HZ you provided and see what I get.

Comment: Note that `SC_CLK_TCK` returns 100, and the man pages on my current Fedora/RHEL systems note that "the corresponding value is obsolete".

Answer (score 5):

sysconf(SC_CLK_TCK) does not give the frequency of the timer interrupts in Linux. It gives the frequency of jiffies which is visible to userspace in things like the counters in various directories in /proc

The actual frequency is hidden from userspace, deliberately. Indeed, some systems use dynamic ticks or "tickless" systems, so there aren't really any at all.

All the userspace interfaces use the value from SC_CLK_TCK, which as far as I can see is always 100 under Linux.

Comment: Yes, it is architecture dependent and is hard-coded at 100 in most (but perhaps not all) architectures in recent kernels.

Comment: OK, let them keep their secrets. I just wanted to know, by what I need to multiply the values from `/proc/stat` and `/proc/<pid>/stat` to get CPU times. I guess 10 ms is enough precision for that...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this:

https://github.com/peppelinux/xt_recent_parser

output is like this:

```
python3 xt_recent_parser.py 
XT_RECENT python parser
<giuseppe.demarco@unical.it>


114.241.108.160, last seen: 2017-03-25 18:21:42 after 13 Connections 
46.165.210.17, last seen: 2017-03-25 13:07:54 after 10 Connections 
61.53.219.162, last seen: 2017-03-25 17:39:17 after 20 Connections 
179.37.141.232, last seen: 2017-03-25 18:08:23 after 2 Connections 
114.42.117.39, last seen: 2017-03-25 13:22:14 after 18 Connections 
177.12.84.234, last seen: 2017-03-25 16:22:14 after 17 Connections
```

I think that it will be easy to edit if you need millisecond conversion, you only have to extend JiffyTimeConverter python class