# In python, how do I get timing information like os.times() for a specific child process?

Tags: python, system

I can use os.times or resource.getrlimit to get user time of the current process, all the children processes, or both.

How do I get timing information for a specific child process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`os.fork`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fork), [`ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, child_pid, ...)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace), then call [`resource.getrusage(RUSAGE_CHILDREN, ...)`](http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html#resource.getrusage). Since you just forked, the attached process will be the only child.

Comment: Super hacky, but it is a general cross-platform solution.

Comment: Yes the ptrace bit makes me uneasy, but that's what Unix is about. It wants you to streamroll over obstacles, so that's how you should use it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can do this in general, but on Linux you can just parse `/proc/<PID>/stat` to find the first four values that you would get from `os.times` for any process.  For example:

```
import sys
import os

if not len(sys.argv) == 2:
    print >> sys.stderr, "Usage: %s <PID>" % (sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)

pid = int(sys.argv[1])

hz = os.sysconf(os.sysconf_names['SC_CLK_TCK'])

with open("/proc/%d/stat" % (pid,)) as fp:
    fields = fp.read().split(' ')[13:17]
    utime, stime, cutime, cstime = [ (float(f) / hz) for f in fields ]
    print "utime in clock ticks:", utime
    print "stime in clock ticks:", stime
    print "cutime in clock ticks:", cutime
    print "cstime in clock ticks:", cstime
```

Presumably you have the process IDs of the child processes you're interested in.

I found out how to get the value of `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` from this question: [Python: How to get number of mili seconds per jiffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189123/python-how-to-get-number-of-mili-seconds-per-jiffy/4189612#4189612) and the information about the fields in `/proc/<PID>/stat` is from the `proc(5)` man page.