# difference between tick count and jiffies

Tags: linux

```
cat /proc/stat gives values in jiffies
cat /proc/[pid]/stat gives values in tick count.
```

What is exactly the  difference between tickcount and jiffies and what is the conversion formula between the two?

Answer (score 3):

jiffy is the duration of one tick of the system timer interrupt. It is not an absolute time interval unit, since its duration depends on the clock interrupt frequency of the particular hardware platform.

The Time Stamp Counter (TSC) is a 64-bit register present on all x86 processors since the Pentium. It counts the number of cycles since reset.

Possibly --> [Python: How to get number of mili seconds per jiffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189123/python-how-to-get-number-of-mili-seconds-per-jiffy)